Choosing projection for taking measurements across one state with multiple state planes
I’m looking at California for example, trying to take measurements between dozens of different points, but unsure what projection to use. The state has like 7 zones and my data is pretty evenly distributed so I’m not sure what to do.
Should I use UTM?
Maybe just pick one zone that overlaps California the most, or just pick one of the state planes and accept there’s going to be some distortion?

Depends on what your question is and how much inaccuracy introduced by distortion matters at the scale of your analysis. UTM Zones 10 and 11 overlap California, and probably wouldn't be bad choices.

You can use ESRI:102600 NAD83 California (Teale) Albers (USFt). It covers the whole state of California.


oh awesome!! are there things like that for every us state? my project will eventually cover all 50 so if there is one for each that would be a godsend

Case by case.  For Conus there's EPSG:42303 NAD83/Albers NorthAm

@Amber Not yet, but the next SPCS2022 by National Geodetic Survey (NGS) will have statewide definitions for all states. Currently planned for late 2025-2026.

Note that this PCS uses Albers which maintains areas, not distances. If you use ArcGIS Pro, search the help for geodesic distances which are projection-agnostic.
